# Using Perl's rename with groups

Tags: files, regular-expression, rename, filenames

I've a set of files named in the following manner:

```
_9978967868768763ghjgj7598983678hjva_week1-6.pdf
_78637832bdsjh275637bkkaww786b_week12-32.pdf
8786767867868978713bkwkhjhkjqw_week1-622.pdf
867813567bdjsbgbadsyu6712353125561235_week100-6.pdf
```

I'm intersted in making use of [`rename`](https://regex101.com) utility to obtain names:

```
 week1-6.pdf
 week12-32.pdf
 week1-622.pdf
 week100-6.pdf
```

The regex to achieve that could be be:

```
(.*)(week.*)
```

which works fine [*(regex101)*](https://regex101.com/r/2JYPmR/1):

[image]

## Question

How do I translate this syntax into rename's expression of format:

```
s/expr1/expr2/[gi]
```

In effect, I want to delete first group.

## Notes

I'm not interested in using `mv` or `sed`-based solution. I want to use `rename`  utility only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using *the proper way* :) just correcting your command (you are very close...) :

```
rename 's/(.*)(week.*)/$2/' *.pdf
```

or to simplify :

```
rename 's/.*(week.*)/$1/' *.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

**`prename`** approach:

```
prename -n 's/.*_(week.*$)/$1/' *_week*.pdf
```

- `$1` - points to the 1st captured group

Comment: @GillesQuenot, look again and you will see that `$1` doesn't figure in the question.